# Spider is just crawling but not scraping why?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to crawl this website

https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_dmd=2&_dkr=1&iconV2Request=true&_ssn=a2z_prime_auto_parts&store_name=a2zprimeautoparts&_oac=1&_pgn=1

I'm trying to go into each product and fetch its name and price and other stuffs but I'm facing an issue that is new to me.

[image]

there are totally 1800+ products , and all have same xpaths which I want to scrape. but it only scraped 96. what could be the issue?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class AutopartSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Autopart'
    allowed_domains = ['www.ebay.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_dmd=2&_dkr=1&iconV2Request=true&_ssn=a2z_prime_auto_parts&store_name=a2zprimeautoparts&_oac=1']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class ='s-item__info clearfix']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='pagination__next icon-link']"))
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield{
            'part_name':response.xpath("//div[@class='vim x-item-title']/h1/span/text()").get()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine but you are facing  a little bit problem that's why you are getting  response status 200/400 which is `follow = True` is not in the right place.You have to place that in the pagination `Rules` instead.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class AutopartSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Autopart'
    allowed_domains = ['www.ebay.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_dmd=2&_dkr=1&iconV2Request=true&_ssn=a2z_prime_auto_parts&store_name=a2zprimeautoparts&_oac=1&_pgn=1']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class ='s-item__info clearfix']/a"), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='pagination__next icon-link']"),follow=True)
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield{
            'part_name':response.xpath("//div[@class='vim x-item-title']/h1/span/text()").get()
        }
```

**Output:**

```
'part_name': 'Rear Wheel Bearing & Hub Assembly For Cadillac Fleetwood 1988-1990 4-Wheel ABS'}
2022-09-07 20:35:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ebay.com/itm/374136029760?hash=item571c3ec240:g:WrsAAOSwd3lirLyQ> (referer: https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_dmd=2&_dkr=1&iconV2Request=true&_ssn=a2z_prime_auto_parts&store_name=a2zprimeautoparts&_oac=1&_pgn=1)
2022-09-07 20:35:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.ebay.com/itm/374136029711?hash=item571c3ec20f:g:sfwAAOSwFFRirLyM>
{'part_name': 'Front Wheel Bearing & Hub Assembly For Pontiac Grand Prix 2003-2008-0238'}
2022-09-07 20:35:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.ebay.com/itm/374136029965?hash=item571c3ec30d:g:QG0AAOSwRC1irLyR>
{'part_name': 'Front Wheel Bearing & Hub Assembly For Toyota Prius C 2012-2015'}
2022-09-07 20:35:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ebay.com/itm/374136029434?hash=item571c3ec0fa:g:JSYAAOSwvspirLyH> (referer: https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_dmd=2&_dkr=1&iconV2Request=true&_ssn=a2z_prime_auto_parts&store_name=a2zprimeautoparts&_oac=1&_pgn=1)
2022-09-07 20:35:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.ebay.com/itm/374136029760?hash=item571c3ec240:g:WrsAAOSwd3lirLyQ>
{'part_name': 'Front Wheel Bearing & Hub Assembly For Ford Taurus X 2008-2009 FWD'}
2022-09-07 20:35:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.ebay.com/itm/374136029434?hash=item571c3ec0fa:g:JSYAAOSwvspirLyH>
{'part_name': 'Rear Wheel Bearing & Hub Assembly For Dodge Viper 1992-1995'}
```

Comment: but the first Rule is about going into each product and scraping things right? so if we want to go in the link to scrape dont we have to set follow = True?

Comment: No, when you set follow= True in the 1st rule then it will  g to the details page along with nested link  which are unnecessary

Comment: You are not getting 1800 items because the hindrance is the dropdown page limit. When I make the pagination in started url using the page items limited the hightest one which is240 then I got  943 items

Comment: still doesnt work :( tried to change that. it scrape few and skips many at the end out of 1800+ i get only 91 items scraped

Comment: I'm getting 943  items

Comment: any suggestion how i can scrape all 1800?

Comment: Yes,  use scrapy default spider instead of crawlspider

Comment: Okay will try the default one